# angular material table saving and restoring sort order into local/-session storage

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive

I would like to store the sorting of a material table in local or session storage. The sort values should be saved for every page since I have multiple tables on different pages.

Comment: What have you tried so far and why doesn't this work for your? Can you share some of your code and its behavior?

Answer (score 4):

I created a custom directive for this. Basically the only values that need to be saved is the **id** of the sorted column and the sort **direction**. I have defined an interface MatSortData that defines these two values. In order to save the state depending on the page the pathname is added to the key.

If you want to save the values in localStorage just replace it with the sessionStorage variable.

```js
const KEY = 'MAT_SORT';


@Directive({
  selector: '[sortingCache]'
})
export class SortingDirective {

  get matSort(): MatSortData {
    return JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem(window.location.pathname + '?' + KEY));
  }

  set matSort(mat: MatSortData) {
    sessionStorage.setItem(window.location.pathname + '?' + KEY, JSON.stringify(mat));
  }

  constructor(
    private el: MatSort,
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if(this.matSort) {
      this.el.active = this.matSort.active;
      this.el.direction = this.matSort.direction;
    }
    this.el.sortChange.subscribe((sort: Sort) => {
      this.matSort = { 
        active: sort.active, 
        direction: sort.direction
      }
    });
  }
}

interface MatSortData {
  active: string;
  direction: SortDirection;
}
```

The directive only needs to be added to one sort header to work. Example html:

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="example">
    <mat-header-cell 
        sortingCache 
        mat-header-cell 
        *matHeaderCellDef 
        mat-sort-header
    >
        Example Header
    </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"></mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```